# Validate blank fields in JavaFX

Tags: java, mysql, validation, javafx

I have problem when trying to validate blank field before insert data in database. I am currently using Netbeans JavaFX Application, scene builder and MySQL.

For this method, it will pass the components inside panel into controller class.

```
private void createProduct(ActionEvent event){
CreateProductController controller = new CreateProductController();
boolean result = controller.create(myPane);
if(result)
{
    System.out.println("Success");
}
}
```

Inside my controller class, I got a validateDetails method which check for blank field before insert and a create method.

```
public boolean create(CreateProductUI panel){
    String name = panel.getNameTextField().getText();
    //And the rest of the components which I removed before it's very long

    //I used if else statement to check 
    boolean invalid = true;
    if(invalid){
        validateDetails(name,desc,priceStr,qtyStr,dateStr,image,category);
        return invalid;
    }else{
    invalid = false;
    Product product1 = new Product(name,desc,price,quantity,dateStr,image,category);
    product1.create();
    return invalid;
    }
}
```

Here comes my validate method:

```
  public void validateDetails(String name,String desc,String priceStr,String qtyStr,String dateStr,Image image,int category){
    if(name.equals("")){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please enter name");       
    }else if(desc.equals("")){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please enter description");
    }else if(priceStr.equals("")){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please enter price");
    }else if(qtyStr.equals("")){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please enter quantity");
    }else if(category <= -1){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please choose category");
    }
}
```

However, the program does not execute to prompt error message when detect any blank field. For example, I leave 2 of my fields blank. It supposed to prompt twice. Instead it just add to my database table.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your methods to be as below:

```
public boolean create(CreateProductUI panel){
 String name = panel.getNameTextField().getText();
 //And the rest of the components which I removed before it's very long

 //I used if else statement to check 
 boolean valid = validateDetails(name,desc,priceStr,qtyStr,dateStr,image,category);

 if(valid) {
     Product product1 = new Product(name,desc,price,quantity,dateStr,image,category);
     product1.create();
 }

 return valid;
 }
}



public boolean validateDetails(String name,String desc,String priceStr,String qtyStr,String dateStr,Image image,int category){

 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 if(name.equals("")){
    sb.append(" name ");
 }
 if(desc.equals("")){
    sb.append(" desc ");     
 }
 if(priceStr.equals("")){
    sb.append(" Price "); 
 }
 if(qtyStr.equals("")){
   sb.append(" Quantity ");     
 }
 if(category <= -1){
sb.append(" Category ");    
 }
 String message = sb.toString();
 if(message.length() > 0) {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please fill up these values: "+message);
   return false;
 }
 return true;
}
```

Comment: Still, it only check for one field. If more than one field with blank, I will hit error.

Comment: Because I am using if else statement so it only check one by one. Is there any other way that I can do for validation?

Comment: Updated the answer with a better approach. Seems like you should brush up your Core Java skills.

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work. What exactly is happening. Update the code in your question that you are using now.

Comment: For example if I leave out name and description, the error message supposed to have name and description. But it only shows name

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `else if` use'`if` condition only. Because in your case if the name field is not empty it won't check the 2nd condition.